# How to represent nested json objects in a cucumber feature file

Tags: json, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have a need to represent JSON object in the feature file. I could use a json file for this for the code to pick up. But this would mean that i cant pass values from the feature file.

```
Scenario: Test

Given a condition is met

Then the following json response is sent
 | json |
 | {"dddd":"dddd","ggggg":"ggggg"}|
```

Above works for a normal json. However if there are nested objects etc then writing the json in a single line like above would make the feature very difficult to read and difficult to fix.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a string to do that, it makes the json much more legible.

```
Then the following json response is sent
  """
   {
      'dddd': 'dddd',
      'ggggg': 'ggggg',
      'somethingelse': {
        'thing': 'thingvalue',
        'thing2': 'thing2value'
      }
    }
  """
```

In the code, you can use it directly:

```
Then(/^the following json response is sent$/) do |message|
  expect(rest_stub.body).to eq(message)
end
```

or something like that.

Comment: Nice and thanks! looks like this will solve my problem.

Comment: But what if I want to verify json together with other parameters, for example:
Then the following <json> response is sent to a <user>
 | user | json |
 | user1 | {"user1": {"dddd":"dddd","ggggg":"ggggg"}}|
 | user2 | {"user2": {"dddd":"dddd","ggggg":"ggggg"}}|

Comment: That's a different question. These are simple questions that can easily be found by searching. I saw 3 good answers at the top when I search google "cucumber json"

Comment: what is this?  `expect(rest_stub.body).to eq(message)`

Comment: [rspect docs for expect(something).to eq(something else)](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers) and the rest_stub.body would be the expected response to the call